# Replace icons in circular-3d buttons by Brandon Pierce

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Brandon Pierce's https://css-tricks.com/circular-3d-buttons/ but want to replace 'fontello' icons by icons of my choice like this one https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/451/451694.svg.
I just can't seem to get it done!

Tried replacing the icon classes by a 'image1' class of my own with random image as background but it just wouldn't show.

Please help!

```
     .nav1 {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav1 li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px; 
}

.nav1 li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav1 a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f7f7f7), to(#e7e7e7));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
  color: #a7a7a7;
  margin: 36px;
  width: 144px;
  height: 144px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 144px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #aaa, inset 0px 2px 3px #fff;
}

.nav1 a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
  left: -18px;
  bottom: -18px;
  right: -18px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 48px #ddd;
}

.nav1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

/* Random class I made to replace icon by image */
.image1 {
background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav1>
            <ul class="nav1">
                <li><a href="#" class="image1"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to do a couple things.  Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgXPqX).

This is your icon

```
.image1:after {
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/451/451694.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

add these two styles to make it sit in the middle of the button without overflowing

```
.nav1 a
{
  ......
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 17px;
}
```